# Why, no matter how hard you try, you can't lose money betting on a submartingale?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Below is the image of theorem on the Upcrossing Inequality of Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples.

[image]

What I don't understand is the remark in the paragraph after the theorem's proof.
Why, no matter how hard you try, you can't lose money betting on a submartingale?

You can get the [pdf on the author's webpage](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTEv5a.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

> .... no matter how hard you try, you can't lose money betting on a submartingale.

Reading it in plain language, out of context, this assertion is clearly false. It is possible (in theory) to lose all $n$ of your first $n$ bets.

But if we accept that this statement is just an informal restatement of the inequality
$E(K\cdot Y)_n \geq 0,$
then all it is saying is that you cannot devise a betting strategy so bad that you should *expect* to lose money with it.
(This assumes the underlying game is favorable to you, so that you have a submartingale.)

Comment: David, thanks for your answer. How does $E(K\cdot Y)_n \geq 0$ relate to a betting strategy so bad you should expect to lose money with it? In which way is $(K\cdot Y)_n$ a bad betting strategy? $K$ is just $1-H$, and $H$ just as defined in the text, is betting while the submartingale in between the $(a,b)$ interval.

Comment: "How does $E(K\cdot Y)n\geq 0$ relate to a betting strategy so bad you should expect to lose money with it?" The relationship is that it _is not_ such a strategy, because no such strategy exists. Why you _might_ think it is a "bad" strategy is that it is the "buy high, sell low" strategy, that is, the exact opposite of the "buy low, sell high" strategy $H.$ (Because $H\in\{0,1\}$ and $K=1-H,$ someone following $K$ bets exactly at the times the person following $H$ does _not_ bet.)